# Weighted L1-norm based Contextual Regularization

Tags: vectors, image-processing, regularization, computer-vision

I am Japanese. I'm not good at English, but thank you.

I am currently reading the following treatise.

"Efficient Image Dehazing with Boundary Constraint and
Contextual Regularization",Gaofeng MENG,et al 2013, IEEE

I don't understand the Weighted L1-norm based Contextual Regularization formula that appears there.

The equation $W(x,y) = e^{-\Vert I(x)-I(y)\Vert^2 / 2 σ^2}    $ is weighting
function.

$W(x,y) $ is weighting function.
$ I(x) $ and $ I(y)   $ is Image.
Why $ I(x) $ and $ I(y)   $ are 1 -dimentional?

In the paper,$ x$ and $ y $ are called two neighboring pixels.
Is this means 4(8)-neighbors of pixel ?

Comment: Is $I(x)$ a vector in $\mathbb R^3$ containing the RGB values for pixel $x$ in the color image $I$?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Yes. In other papers, image $ I $ is sometimes a grayscale image.

I also deal with grayscale images such as a medical image.

Comment: What do you mean by $1$-dimensional? For a color image $I(x)$ is a vector in $\mathbb R^3$. That makes sense.

Comment: I thought$ W (x, y)$ was Euclidean coordinates, so I thought $I(x)$ was one-dimensional.  
($x$ and $y = 0,1,2.......N$  ; $N $is image matrix size)

  I understand that  $I(x)$ is a vector.　If $I(x)$I is a grayscale image, is $I(x)$  a vector in $ \mathbb {R^1}$ ? Also, does $I(y)$  mean 4 or 8-neighbors of pixel ?

Comment: It's important to distinguish between $I$, which is an image, and $I(x)$, which is the RGB vector for that image at pixel location $x$. I haven't checked exactly how the paper has defined these objects, but I would guess that $I$ is an $m \times n \times 3$ array of numbers and $x = (i,j)$ is a pair of integers with $1 \leq i \leq m, 1 \leq j \leq n$. So $x$ specifies a pixel location in the image $i$. And $I(x)$ is the RGB vector $I(i,j,:) \in \mathbb R^3$ (to use Matlab style notation).

Comment: And $y$ is a pixel location also. When the paper says that $y$ is a neighbor of $x$, it probably means that $y$ is either a $4$-neighbor or an $8$-neighbor of $x$.

Comment: Thanks you. Now I understand.  Is it okay that $W(x,y)$ is $W(m,n,:)$ ?

Comment: $W$ is a function that takes as input a pixel location $x  = (i_1, j_1)$ and another pixel location $y = (i_2,j_2)$ and returns as output the number $e^{-\| I(x) - I(y)\|^2/2\sigma^2}$. This number quantifies how similar pixels $x$ and $y$ are. The largest possible value that $W(x,y)$ can have occurs when $I(x) = I(y)$. And if $I(x)$ differs significantly from $I(y)$ then $W(x,y)$ is very small.

Comment: Oh, I see.　So, at the edge of the image, $W(x,y)$ has a very small weight.
That means,  if $y$  is  a 4-neighbor and $x=(i,j)$ is a center pixel ,$W(x,y)$ has a $W(i,j,i-1,j)$,$W(i,j,i+1,j)$,$W(i,j,i,j-1)$,$W(i,j,i,j+1)$, or is  W (i, j)  the sum of the differences between the vectors in the 4-neighbor.